# SD-card reader suddenly stopped recognizing cards

Tags: drivers, realtek, sd-card, card-reader

Recently my sd-card reader stopped working.

The weird part: 5 minutes earlier *etcher* successfully wrote an image to an sd-card. 
After wanting to write another imagefile, no sd-cards could get mounted/unmounted/recognized anymore.

The device refusing to work properly:

```
#$ sudo lspci -v
  ...
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at dd100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number [xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx]
    Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
  ...
```

Since the device was working like a litteral 5 minutes before, I'm assuming an error 
in either the driver/module or an unremoved device lock which I can't find.

There are several things I've tried to fix it and it failed:

- Turning computer off and on again
- Since the sd-cards used were micro sd-card with adapter, several adapters were tried
- Several sd-cards were tried (in case the card itself broke)
- An online suggestion of reinstalling udisks2
- An online suggestion of `sudo apt-get install --reinstall udev*`
- Using a *LiveCD* on a usb-drive
- Using another usb sd-card reader

More information:

I'm currently running Linux Mint 18 with Xfce desktop environment on my Dell Precision 5510

```
  Linux kernel:
    4.4.0-103-generic 
  Version:
    #126-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 16:23:28 UTC 2017
```

The running modules which relate to the sd-card reader are:

```
#$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
  ...
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
  ...
```

EDIT:

- Using an other sd-card reader (via usb) worked after all, I guess I shouldn't conclude something, if it is not working with the cheapest of hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Own Answer:

Using an external sd-card reader worked after all. The internal SD-card reader of my machine just broke, which hasn't anything to do with any config or software.

Answer (score 0):

My Asus Zenbook Pro did the same thing.

I think the Card reader is (frpm sudo lspci -v):

```
d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at dd100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=9 Masked-
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Capabilities: [158] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [168] #19
Capabilities: [188] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [190] L1 PM Substates
Kernel driver in use: nvme
Kernel modules: nvme
```

In addition to the suggestions you posted, I tried to get it to work inside a Windoze 10 VM, and still no luck.

I guess I'll get a USB reader.  Wish I had seen your post earlier before pulling out my all my hair!